# VBA EXcel - I am getting an error (400) if using error trap getting no object/application defined error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

My excel sheet has these data, 7 columns

```
sl.no | bed | 2| 4| 3|4|3|
```

some times column no 7 is empty, and then only I'm getting error

And my code

---

```
Sub sup_cal_area_sft()
Dim lru, plru As Long
Dim myless As String
Dim ttr_l, ttr_p, ttr_nql, ttr_nqp, trft As Variant

On Error GoTo Errorcatch

myless = "*" & "LESS" & "*"

    With ActiveSheet
        lru = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp).Row
        plru = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "h").End(xlUp).Row + 2
    End With
For i = plru To lru

ttr_l = "=PRODUCT((C" & i & "+D" & i & "/12)*(E" & i & "+F" & i & "/12)*-G" & i & ")"
ttr_p = "=PRODUCT((C" & i & "+D" & i & "/12)*(E" & i & "+F" & i & "/12)*G" & i & ")"

ttr_nql = "=PRODUCT((C" & i & "+D" & i & "/12)*-(E" & i & "+F" & i & "/12)" 
ttr_nqp = "=PRODUCT((C" & i & "+D" & i & "/12)*(E" & i & "+F" & i & "/12)" 
   trft = "=PRODUCT((C" & i & "+D" & i & "/12)*G" & i & ")"

If Cells(i, 5) <> "" Then

       If UCase(Cells(i, 2).Value) Like myless Then 'negative value

              If Cells(i, 7) <> "" Then
                Cells(i, 8) = ttr_l
              Else
                 Cells(i, 8) = ttr_nql
              End If



           ElseIf Not UCase(Cells(i, 2).Value) Like myless Then 'positive Value
             If Cells(i, 7) <> "" Then
                Cells(i, 8) = ttr_p
             Else
                Cells(i, 8) = ttr_nqp
              End If
          End If

' RFT Calculaion

   ElseIf Cells(i, 3) <> "" And Cells(i, 5) = "" and cells(i,4) <> "" Then
     Cells(i, 8) = trft


' Blank
Else
    Cells(i, 8) = ""

End If

Next i

Cells(lru + 3, 2).Select

exit sub

Errorcatch:
MsgBox Err.Description 

End Sub
```

Comment: welcome to superuser. Which line gives you the error message? Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: `plru`, `ttr_nqp` - We have naming conventions for a reason :).

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a bracket on the lines:

```
ttr_nql = "=PRODUCT((C" & i & "+D" & i & "/12)*-(E" & i & "+F" & i & "/12)" 
ttr_nqp = "=PRODUCT((C" & i & "+D" & i & "/12)*(E" & i & "+F" & i & "/12)"
```

I believe they should be:

```
ttr_nql = "=PRODUCT((C" & i & "+D" & i & "/12)*-(E" & i & "+F" & i & "/12))" 
ttr_nqp = "=PRODUCT((C" & i & "+D" & i & "/12)*(E" & i & "+F" & i & "/12))"
```

Note that you have the `On Error GoTo Errorcatch` set up, however this is probably stopping you getting decent debug information (such as what line actually failed). As such, I'd remove that whilst trying to debug issues.